# Using httr::GET() on macOS produces certificate error

Tags: r, macos, httr

Trying to access an API with `httr` on macOS produces a certificate error.

```r
httr::GET("https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Indicator/List")
#> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle): SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

However, running this on multiple Windows machines is successful, with no additional setup other than installing `httr` and running the above code (it shouldn't need a certificate). Is it something server-side that is preventing access for some reason or something client-side that I can adjust? I was unable to find anything online about general certificate issues with `httr` and macOS.

I can successfully access other APIs on this machine using `httr`, so it leads me to believe this is a server-side issue, but don't have enough experience or knowledge to fully troubleshoot this on my own.

Below is my session info for reference. Thanks for any help you can provide.

**Session info:**

```r
#> R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.4
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.9/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.9.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6    digest_0.6.25   R6_2.4.1        magrittr_1.5   
#>  [5] evaluate_0.14   highr_0.8       httr_1.4.1      rlang_0.4.6    
#>  [9] stringi_1.4.6   curl_4.3        rmarkdown_2.1   tools_4.0.0    
#> [13] stringr_1.4.0   xfun_0.14       yaml_2.2.1      compiler_4.0.0 
#> [17] htmltools_0.4.0 knitr_1.28
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the exact same problem since yesterday. After looking things up, turns out a common root CA certificate expired on 30th May (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139904/api-request-and-error-in-curlcurl-fetch-memoryurl-handle-handle-ssl-cer)). In general, what solved my error is to force `Curl` (which supports `httr` functions) to ignore the certificate:

```
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))
options(RCurlOptions = list(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))
options(rsconnect.check.certificate = FALSE)
```

I knows close to nothing about server issues. But this works for me, so I hope it does for you too!

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar SSL sertificate problem with the mistake

> no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name

Solved with

```r
httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE, ssl_verifyhost = FALSE))
```